# Unable to Access Content of iFrame Within Blogger Post Page Using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, iframe

`<iframe frameborder="0" class="ZW3ZFc editable" id="nsoPic1674433476127" style="padding: 0px; background-color: white;"></iframe>`

And it's `HTML` :

`<html style="background:none transparent;min-width:0;"><head><style></style><style type="text/css">td.tr-caption:empty:after{color:gray;content:"Add caption";}</style><style type="text/css">img { cursor: move; }</style></head><body g_editable="true" hidefocus="true" contenteditable="" class="editable " id="nsoPic1674463885278" style="min-width: 0px; direction: ltr; text-align: left;" role="textbox"><p>&nbsp;rwerwer</p></body></html>`

I am getting `NoSuchElementException` error when trying to enter the above iframe. Below is the code. I just want to enter the text box and use `send_keys`.

I tried to this for entering iframe:

```
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, "iframe"))
element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id=""]/p')
element.send_keys("Hello")
```

It seems blogger uses a different id for each post post screen so I tried using the id number but failed. I try to use `CLASS_NAME` but still I keep getting the same error. I guess I can't get inside the iframe. Can you help me? The whole code block is below.

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException

#information
title = ""
response = ""
blogpost_email = ""
blogpost_password = ""

#blogger entering
driver = uc.Chrome(use_subprocess=True)
url1 = 'https://www.blogger.com/'
driver.get(url1)

#waiting page
time.sleep(5)

driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/header/div[1]/div[2]/a[1]/span').click()
#waiting page
time.sleep(5)

#entering information
email_block = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="identifierId"]')
email_block.send_keys(blogpost_email)
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="identifierNext"]/div/button').click()

#waiting page
time.sleep(10)

#entering information
block_password_block = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="password"]/div[1]/div/div[1]/input')
block_password_block.send_keys(blogpost_password)
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="passwordNext"]/div/button/span').click()

#controlling there is no blog
try:
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="yDmH0d"]/c-wiz/div/div/div/div[2]/div[4]/div[1]/button/span').click()
except NoSuchElementException:
    pass

#waiting page
time.sleep(30)

#entering new post
driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'MIJMVe').click()

#waiitng page
time.sleep(10)

#entering information
post_title = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="yDmH0d"]/c-wiz[2]/div/c-wiz/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[1]/input')
post_title.click()
post_title.send_keys(title)

driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, "iframe"))
element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id=""]/p')
element.send_keys("Hello")
driver.switch_to.default_content()

#publishing
publish_button = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'ZFr60d CeoRYc')
publish_button.click()

#submiting
submit_button = drive.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'RveJvd snByac')
submit_button.click()
```

Comment: This need login to the web can you add the `HTML` source for the element you're getting error ?

Comment: I added it to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that these commands are different

```
driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, 'iframe') # the one you are using
driver.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'iframe')
```

The first one returns the first iframe found in the html, while the second one returns the list of all the iframe. The page to create a post contains several iframe, moreover the number of iframe and their ids change each time you create a new post. Also, the iframe you want is never the first one in the html, so when in your code you run

```
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, "iframe"))
```

you are switching to the wrong iframe. The iframe you want has the following unique xpath

```
xpath = "//c-wiz[contains(@style,'visibility: visible')]/descendant::iframe[contains(@class,'ZW3ZFc')]"
```

so you can switch to it with

```
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element(By.XPATH, xpath))
```

and then write text with

```
textbox = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'body.editable')
textbox.send_keys("Hello")
```

Comment: It worked, thank you for your help! Additionally, where can I get the unique xpath or learn how to write it?

Comment: @Adzetto You have to open the DevTools (right click -> inspect) then press CTRL+F and try different xpath. I started simply with `//iframe[contains(@class,'ZW3ZFc')]` but it found 2 results, so I started looking for a descendant - of the correct iframe - having a unique attribute. I noticed a strange element `c-wiz` and searching for `//c-wiz/descendant::iframe[contains(@class,'ZW3ZFc')]` it found 2 results, the wrong one had `visibility:hidden` while the correct one had `visibility:visible`. So using this fact I wrote the final xpath